# Python 2.7 automatically log on website

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just want to know how to log on a webpage automatically using python 2.7, the example website is https://extranet.misoenergy.org/Pages/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fextranet.misoenergy.org%2fPages%2fHome.aspx

I have searched for some useful tips, however, this website has special sources that I am not so sure how to deal with.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks

Here is my code so far

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://extranet.misoenergy.org/Pages/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fextranet.misoenergy.org%2fPages%2fHome.aspx")

from twill.commands import *
go("https://extranet.misoenergy.org/Pages/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fextranet.misoenergy.org%2fPages%2fHome.aspx")

fv("1", "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_username", "***.com")
fv("1", "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_password", "****")

submit('0')
```

But there is an error: "PasswordControl instance has no attribute '_click'"

Comment: Look up the requests python library.  There are good examples there http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: @cbron, I have attached my code there, but there is an error, I don't know how to solve

Comment: I've never used webbrowser before. I would approach this problem with requests and POST your values to the form endpoint if you know what they require. If you want to keep using webbrowser just run through your code with the python CLI and do some searching around for the right button to click, it looks like you're clicking on the password input.

Comment: @cbron The "Login" button on that website is not a simple `form` button that issues a `POST` but clicking runs some piece of `JavaScript`. Maybe @younger could mimic this by doing what the piece of `JavaScript` does directly via `http`. I will not create an account with that site for further investigation, but if I had an account, I would try to use `Basic` authentication with the credentials to find out whether that websites supports `Basic` too, before diving into the `ajax` stuff...